# Fading certain images in force layout using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to filtering out images which are present in arrMatchFile. So those images whose url is not present in arrMatchFile are to be fade out using style("opacity", 0.5) whereas those whose url is present should be seen as it is. But here images whose url is in arrMatchFile isn't getting displayed. I suspect I might overriding it as href tag is missing when i see it in firebug console. Below is the code for this scenario.

```
var arrFileUrl = [], arrBrightness = [], arrPattern = [], arrSize = [], arrMatchFile = [];

d3.csv("data/Images.csv", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {

        arrFileUrl.push(d['FingerImageName']);
        arrBrightness.push(d['Brightness']);
        arrPattern.push(d['Pattern']);
        arrSize.push(d['Size']);

    });

    //console.log(data);

    var boolBrig = arrBrightness.contains(brightness);
    var boolSize = arrSize.contains(pixel);

    if(boolBrig === true && boolSize === true){

        data.forEach(function(d){
            if(d['Brightness'] === brightness && d['Size'] === pixel && d['Pattern'] === pattSelect){
                arrMatchFile.push(d['FingerImageName']);
            }

        }); 
    }


    var nodes = d3.range(arrFileUrl.length).map(function(i) {
      return {index: i};
    });

    var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .gravity(0.05)
    .charge(-1700)
    .friction(0.5)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function (d,i) {
            if(arrMatchFile.contains(arrFileUrl[i])) {
                return arrFileUrl[i];
            }
    })
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("width", 120)
    .attr("height", 160)
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .call(force.drag)
    .style("opacity", 0.5);


    node.attr("xlink:href", function (d,i) {
            if(arrMatchFile.contains(arrFileUrl[i]) === false) {
                return arrFileUrl[i];
            }
    })
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .call(force.drag)
    .style("opacity", 2);


    svg.transition()
    .duration(1000);


    function tick(e) {

      // Push different nodes in different directions for clustering.
      var k = 4 * e.alpha;
      nodes.forEach(function(o, i) {
        o.y += i & 1 ? k : -k;
        o.x += i & 2 ? k : -k;
      });

      node.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think carefully about what's the difference between images in arrMatchFile and others. The "xlink:href" shouldn't be different (you still need the image in both cases, so you should use:

```
node 
 ...
 .attr("xlink:href", function (d,i) {
            return arrFileUrl[i];
 })
 ...
```

However, the *opacity* is different, hence your test appears in the "opacity" attribute:

```
...
.style("opacity", function(d,i){
        if(arrMatchFile.contains(arrFileUrl[i])) {
            return 0.5;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }           
});
```

---

some additional advice:

- every function used in .attr() and .style() should return something, whatever their arguments. So: always consider the `else` case of any `if` and make sure you `return` something relevant for this case
- you seem to naturally like to have a set of arrays to describe your data (one array for each possible information). This is the least comfortable way when you work with d3. You would make much shorter code by simply having **one** array of objects, each object containing all the information you can give it. For example, instead of using a separate array for your matching files, do the following

  ```
    data.forEach(function(d){
       if(d['Brightness'] === brightness && d['Size'] === pixel &&   d['Pattern'] === pattSelect){
          d.matchFile = true;
       } else {
          d.matchFile = false;
       }
     });
  ```

  you can then test this field as follows:

  ```
   .style("opacity", function(d,i){
     if (d.matchFile) {
      return 0.5;
     } else {
      return 1;
     }           
   });
  ```

  In principle, you shouldn't need all your `arr...` variables.
- your booleans `boolBrig` and `boolSize` are redundant in your current code, you could simply remove everything related to them.

Comment: Hi @laurent your solution is working for me however I need to have to have those arr.. variables because I need to access file names when appending images to node. Anyway thanks for solution :)

Comment: Hi @laurent I have one more thing to cover how can I group them on basis of their pattern type which is present in arrPattern?

Comment: You can access filenames directly from your array of objects, with `d.FingerImageName`. For grouping, it is not clear what you want... something like this? http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021953

Comment: Hi @laurent I want exactly like this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/1021841/ however instead of circle I have images and also I had already posted question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935329/grouping-nodes-in-d3-js-in-multiforce-layout. Its grouping but not logically like on basis of arrInt values whose value's are many 0's, 1's and 2's.